# ETH was automatically sent to a different Public Address after successful deposit in my meta mask

Tags: blockchain, metamask, etherscan, scam, phishing

Same thing happened to me after depositing ETH to my public address it was automatically sent to another address

Comment: It looks like your account is compromised and someone else has your private key.